# How to call mock-like reflection api method in unit testing when non-existing method call is made by object?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito, static-methods

I am using mockito 1.7.4. I use a custom API to verify intended behavior in my current service, I can see the codes via decompiling. I built my logic on top of this behaviour verification and I want to unit test it. The verification step (which as API based) is:

```
private static boolean verifySomeBehaviour(String verifierMethodName, VerifierClass vf){
    CustomObject custObj = someService.getCustomObject("objectName");
    Method mthd = custObj.getClass().getMethod(verifierMethodName,VerifierClass.class);
    return mthd.invoke(custObj,vf);
}
```

In my testing environment, I mocked the someService.getCustomObject("objectName") part and it shows up perfectly. However, because the mock object does not contain given verifier method it throws a NoSuchMethodException.

In order to solve this, I added a method object (like mocking the reflection api's Method):

```
    Method mthd = null;
    try {
        mthd = co.getClass().getMethod("getClass",null);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Because the object has getClass method and requires no parameters it perfectly builds a method. After that I want to call above method (named mthd) instead of orijinal one and change the invocation result as I want(true or false):

```
Mockito.when(co.getClass().getMethod(verifierMethodName,VerifierClass.class)).thenReturn(mthd);
Mockito.when(mthd.invoke(co, vf)).thenReturn(true);
```

Afterall that, it still gives me NoSuchMethodException at     `Mockito.when(co.getClass().getMethod(verifierMethodName,VerifierClass.class)).thenReturn(mthd)`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: how to mock a non existent method? You can't. it also makes no sense to try to. Probably you are passing wrong parameters, and the signature is not recognized, or you've made a typo in the name

Comment: Actually I want to return another method when a method call is made although the method does not present in object.

Comment: how about you just build an entire mock for your CustomObject, which includes a specific implementation for getClass() which returns what you want?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a solution but it is a long one. I am looking for a trick if it exists.

Comment: .. That somewhat is the trick

Comment: May be a way to ignore the exception and continue with thenReturn(mthd). Thanks for your support by the way.

Comment: you can't call what isn't there, and you can't use mockito to do a .thenReturn(...) on your custObj, because it's a local variable. have your 'getCustomObject(...)' return a fully implemented version of what you need

Comment: You can only stub a method of a mock. `Mockito.when(co.getClass().getMethod(…))` contains two method invocations, the latter, `getMethod` is not called on a mock. In `when(mthd.invoke(…))` the method also isn’t invoked on a mock. Whether `getClass()` can be changed at all, is another question.

Comment: Is it possible to skip the internal parts and directly mock the verifySomeBehaviour method ?

Comment: And if it is possible(I think it is), is it right to skip internals and just mock the method? I think it will be trivial solution.

Comment: This seems to be an xy problem. Why is your mock object lacking the method and why don’t you try to fix that issue, instead of manipulating Reflection?

Comment: I solved the problem spying the class which owns the verifySomeBehaviour method and added doReturn() to adjust result when the verifySomeBehaviour method called.